# Angular pass data between components using Input() doesnt trigger ngOnChanges

Tags: angular

I have two components parent and child component, I'm using @Input() for passing data between the parent to child.
At the initialization, it works I get the data from the parent.
but after changing this data it didn't reflect in the child input component.

I'm not using onPush strategy.

contacts-at-company.component - html, which include the contacts-at-company-results component as following;

```
<contacts-at-company-results
      *ngIf="!isPersonSearchLoading && isShowingResults && !showFilters"
      [personList]="personList">

    </contacts-at-company-results>
```

personList is an input in contacts-at-company-results components

when i change the personList in code it doesnt get reflected in the child component
and ngOnChanges doesnt get called.

```
export classContactsAtCompanyResultsComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
 @Input() personList;
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    alert(changes);
  }
```

in the parent:

```
  updateSearchResults(data) {
      this.personList = [...data];
  }
```

Comment: Is `personList` an array? If yes, I would try `this.personList = [...data]` in `updateSearchResults`.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new reference

```
updateSearchResults(data) {

 this.personList = [... data] ;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ngOnChanges()` is only called when change detection updates a binding to an @Input(). If the input is changed imperatively from somewhere then it isn't called.

Just make `personList` a getter/setter for code to be executed every time when the property is updated.